# How to include {%url%} in js innerHTML?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

mainPage.html

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        <div style="display: flex">
            <div id="menu" class="menu"></div>
        </div>
        <a class="menu-item" href="{% url 'users' %}">users</a> //this WORKS
    </body>
    <script src="{% static 'js/menu.js' %}"></script>
</html>
```

menu.js

```
document.getElementById('menu').innerHTML = `                   
                <a class="menu-item" href="{% url 'users' %}">users</a> //this DONT work
`;
```

url.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("",views.mainPage),
    path("users/",views.users,name='users'),
]
```

How to make the url also work in menu.js? it works when I put it in html file.

Comment: Django template engine does not preprocess js or css code. Use if-else in the template if need. Or describe _what_ you are trying to accomplish, not _how_. This is clearly an XY problem.

Answer (score 0):

Django template tags are interpreted on the server side. But JavaScript is interpreted on the browser side.

So if you're trying to use the Django **url** template tag within a JavaScript **innerHTML** in a Django template, you'll need to make sure that the JavaScript code is executed within the context of the Django template.

One way to do this is to define a JavaScript variable within your Django template that contains the URL generated by the **url** template tag, and then use that variable within your **innerHTML** call.

```
<!-- in your Django template -->
{% url 'users' as users_url %}
<script>
    var users_url = "{% filter escapejs %}{{ users_url }}{% endfilter %}";
    document.getElementById('menu').innerHTML = `<a class="menu-item" href="${users_url}">users</a>`;
</script>
```

Here **escapejs** filter is used to ensure that the URL is properly escaped for use within a JavaScript string.